# Modify request Headers using Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to Modify a request header using a Chrome Extension. However I don't know why my Code doesn't work. It looks something like this:

```
var c = "example=example";
chrome.webRequest.onBeforeSendHeaders.addListener(function(details){
  var headers = details.requestHeaders;
  for(h=0;h<headers.length;h++){
      if(headers[h].name != "Cookie"){
        continue;
      }
      headers[h].value = c;
      return {requestHeaders:headers};

}, {urls:["<all_urls>"]}, ["requestHeaders", "blocking", "extraHeaders"]);
```

This doesn't work. In my manifest, I declared `"webRequest", "webRequestBlocking", "<all_urls>"` as permissions. 
When I `console.log` the details in an onBeforeSendHeaders event, the headers are modified, but not when I do the same in onSendHeaders.

Comment: `if(headers[h].name.toLowerCase() !== "cookie"){`

Comment: As for onSendHeaders, the documentation says you can't modify anything there, it's only informational.

Comment: @wOxxOm I used onSendHeaders just to do console.log to look at the headers. When I looked at the headers in onBeforeSendHeaders the values were modified/right, but at onSendHeaders they were wrong again.

Comment: It probably means you have another extension that modified the requests afterwards. Or there's a bug in onSendHeaders and it shows the old headers. Either way, use an external tool like Fiddler proxy or Charles to inspect the real request.